# How to set the second layout manager for a recyclerview inside another recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make a recyclerview inside another recyclerview ,first recycler works but i can't set the layoutmanager for the second recyclerview .I tried to invoke the parent layout of that recycler but i think it doesn't work like that . I am working in a fragment .

I am receiving this error :

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
```

This is the Fragment :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_received_commands, container, false);

    receivedCommandsRecycler = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.received_commands_recycler);
    orderRecycler = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.order_recycler);
    layoutManagerReceivedCommands = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManagerOrder = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    receivedCommandsRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerReceivedCommands);
    orderRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerOrder);


    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mRef = mDatabase.getReference("RestaurantUnu").child("Comenzi");

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ReceivedCommandsModel> optionsReceivedCommands = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ReceivedCommandsModel>()
            .setQuery(mRef, ReceivedCommandsModel.class)
            .build();


    adapterReceivedCommands = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ReceivedCommandsModel, ReceivedCommandsViewHolder>(optionsReceivedCommands) {

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ReceivedCommandsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_command,parent,false);

            fragmentItem = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_layout);
            return new ReceivedCommandsViewHolder(itemView);


        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ReceivedCommandsViewHolder receivedCommandsViewHolder, int i, @NonNull final ReceivedCommandsModel receivedCommandsModel) {
            receivedCommandsViewHolder.tableNmb.setText(receivedCommandsModel.getMasa());
        }
    };
    adapterReceivedCommands.startListening();
    receivedCommandsRecycler.setAdapter(adapterReceivedCommands);


    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<OrderModel> optionsOrderModel = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<OrderModel>()
            .setQuery(mRef, OrderModel.class)
            .build();


    adapterOrder = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<OrderModel, OrderViewHolder>(optionsOrderModel) {

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public OrderViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_order,parent,false);

            //fragmentItem = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_layout);
            return new OrderViewHolder(itemView);


        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final OrderViewHolder orderViewHolder, int i, @NonNull final OrderModel orderModel) {
            orderViewHolder.comandaTxt.setText(orderModel.getComandaTxt());
        }
    };
    adapterOrder.startListening();
    orderRecycler.setAdapter(adapterOrder);


    return view;
}
```

Layout xml that i am using for the first recycler:

```
<LinearLayout
android:paddingTop="8dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="140dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="124dp"
    android:id="@+id/item_layout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="108dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="56"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="64sp"
        android:id="@+id/table_number"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/order_recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:src="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

Comment: Please, copy the layout xml content.

Comment: @SzilárdGerlei hope it helps

Comment: If you mean that there is a child `RecyclerView` in every item of a parent `RecyclerView`, then the child `RecyclerView`s need to be handled in the parent's `Adapter`. They won't be found in the `Fragment`'s layout in `onCreateView()`, which is why you're getting that `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your second RecyclerView is inside `R.layout.item_command`, you need to call `findViewById(R.id.received_commands_recycler)` and `setLayoutManager` from within your outer adapter's `onBindViewHolder` method.

Right now, you're searching for the nested `RecyclerView` in the outer layout, and it's not there until the `ViewHolder` is bound.

Comment: Like this ? Inside the onBindViewHolder `layoutManagerOrder = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
                orderRecycler = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.order_recycler);
                orderRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerOrder);` I can't manage to make it work

Comment: I managed to do it , after i read your comm more times . Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do when I need a list inside a ViewHolder is to create a custom view that will contain this second recycler view. And then inside the custom view, you set the layoutmanager.

```
<LinearLayout
  android:paddingTop="8dp"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="140dp"
  android:orientation="vertical">

 ...

  <your.package.OrdersView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

 ....
```